# How to make 2D bullet have smooth bounce?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics

I have an example:

```js
//Code that need to run
var codeRun = `
function* example(x, y) {
  x = x || Shmup.advanced.data().scene.size.x / 2;
  y = y || Shmup.advanced.data().scene.size.y / 3.75;
  var angle = 0;
  while (true) {
    //for (var i = 1; i <= 360; i ++) {
      var obj = fireBullet(x, y, 5, angle);
      Shmup.util.task(testing, [obj], {update: true, reset: false});
      angle += /*360 / 8 +*/ 0.5;
    //}
    yield* wait(1);
  }
}
Shmup.util.task(example, [], {update: true, reset: false});
//The function above will create a generator and push it to a large array that will
//run every generator in it for every update

function* testing(obj) {
  //Main part of bouncing
  var angleBounce = 0, bounceTime = 2;
  //yield one frame
  yield;
  while (bounceTime > 0) {
    yield;
    //Function below will check for collision with border
    if (Shmup.util.out(5, obj.position)) {
      /*
      The "type" variable is just for choosing collision type,
      in this case "5": all 4 walls, return boolean
      function (type, position) {
        return position.x < 0 ||
        data.scene.size.x < position.x ||
        position.y < 0 ||
        data.scene.size.y < position.y;
      }
      And "0" is return integer what wall bullet hit
      */
      switch (Shmup.util.out(0, obj.position)) {
        case 1:
        case 3: {
          //Check if hit vertical wall
          angleBounce = 90;
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        case 4: {
          angleBounce = 180;
        }
        break;
      }
      obj.angle = Shmup.math.angle.bounce(obj.angle,
                  Shmup.math.angle.degree.radian(angleBounce));
      /*
      The function above:
      function bounce(angle, mirrorAngle) {
        return 2 * mirrorAngle - angle;
      }
      */
      bounceTime -= 1;
    }
  }
  while (true) {
    //This loop will just check if bullet hit wall then break it
    yield;
    if (Shmup.util.out(5, obj.position)) {
      break;
    }
  }
  //Delete bullet
  obj.data.isDelete = true;
}

//Nothing really important from here
function fireBullet(x, y, speed, angle) {
  return Shmup.projectile.bullet.add({
    position: {
      x: x,
      y: y,
    },
    angle: Shmup.math.angle.degree.radian(angle),
    speed: speed,
    data: {
      graphic: (function() {
        var bulletImg = new PIXI.Sprite(spritesheet);
        bulletImg.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
        stage.addChild(bulletImg);
        return bulletImg;
      })(),
      isDelete: false,
    },
    update: function(projectile) {
      projectile.data.graphic.position.set(projectile.position.x, projectile.position.y);
      projectile.data.graphic.rotation = -projectile.angle;// - Math.PI;
      if (deleteProjectile === true || projectile.data.isDelete === true) {
        if (Shmup.advanced.process().active.length <= 1) {
          deleteProjectile = false;
        }
        stage.removeChild(projectile.data.graphic);
        Shmup.projectile.bullet.remove(projectile);
      }
    },
  });
}
function* wait(data) {
  var waiter = Shmup.util.count({
    min: 0,
    max: data,
    change: 1,
    reset: true,
  });
  while (waiter() < data) {
    yield;
  }
}`;


//From here nothing inportant
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.fitWindow = function() {
  var resize = function() {
    var rateWidth = this.width / window.innerWidth;
    var rateHeight = this.height / window.innerHeight;
    var rate = this.height / this.width;
    if (rateWidth > rateHeight) {
      this.style.width = innerWidth + "px";
      this.style.height = innerWidth * rate + "px";
    } else {
      this.style.width = innerHeight / rate + "px";
      this.style.height = innerHeight + "px";
    }
  }.bind(this);
  window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
  resize();
};

// requestAnim shim layer by Paul Irish
//http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(callback, element){
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
})();

var keyboard = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false,
  shift: false,
};
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      keyboard.left = true;
      break;
    case 38:
      keyboard.up = true;
      break;
    case 39:
      keyboard.right = true;
      break;
    case 40:
      keyboard.down = true;
      break;
    case 16:
      keyboard.shift = true;
      break;
  }
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      keyboard.left = false;
      break;
    case 38:
      keyboard.up = false;
      break;
    case 39:
      keyboard.right = false;
      break;
    case 40:
      keyboard.down = false;
      break;
    case 16:
      keyboard.shift = false;
      break;
  }
}, false);
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
    case 38:
    case 39:
    case 40:
    case 16:
      //e.preventDefault();
    break;
  }
}, false);

function isSlow() {
  if (keyboard.shift) {
    return player.slow;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

//Pre-processing
var renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(
  384 * 2, 448 * 2,
  {antialias: false, transparent: true, resolution: 1}
);
renderer.autoResize = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
renderer.view.fitWindow();

var stage = new PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer(10000 , {
  rotation: true,
  alpha: false,
  scale: false,
  uvs: false,
});

var spritesheet;

Shmup.configs({
  maxProjectile: {
    bullet: 10000,
    laser: 1,
    curve: 1,
    curveNode: 1,
  },
  scene: {
    size: {
      x: 384 * 2,
      y: 448 * 2,
    },
    boundary: 10,
  },
});

Shmup.advanced.performance.configs({
  smoothing: 10,
  maxMs: 0,
});

PIXI.loader
  .add("test", "https://cdn.rawgit.com/Trung0246/Shmup/stable/img/down_arrow_icon.png")
  .load(setup);

//Variables
var player = {
  x: Shmup.advanced.data().scene.size.x / 2,
  y: Shmup.advanced.data().scene.size.y - 50,
  speed: 3.75,
  slow: 0.55,
};

//Main process
function setup() {
  spritesheet = PIXI.loader.resources["test"].texture;
  console.log("Done Loading... Now entering main loop...");
  loop();
}

function loop() {
  Shmup.advanced.performance.start();
  if (keyboard.left) {
    player.x -= player.speed * isSlow();
  } else if (keyboard.right) {
    player.x += player.speed * isSlow();
  };
  if (keyboard.up) {
    player.y -= player.speed * isSlow();
  } else if (keyboard.down) {
    player.y += player.speed * isSlow();
  };
  player.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(player.x, Shmup.advanced.data().scene.size.x));
  player.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(player.y, Shmup.advanced.data().scene.size.y));
  Shmup.update();
  renderer.render(stage);
 Shmup.advanced.performance.end();
  requestAnimFrame(loop);
}

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = "Frame: " + Shmup.advanced.data().frame + "<br/>" + "Count: " + Shmup.advanced.process().active.length;
  document.getElementById("data3").innerHTML = "MS: " + Shmup.advanced.performance.ms().toFixed(3);
}, 0);
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML =  "FPS: " + Shmup.advanced.performance.fps().toFixed(3);
}, 50);

document.getElementById("evalScript").onclick = function() {
  eval(codeRun);
};

document.getElementById("clearTask").onclick = function() {
  Shmup.advanced.temp().task = [];
};

var deleteProjectile = false;

document.getElementById("clearProjectile").onclick = function() {
  if (deleteProjectile === false) {
    deleteProjectile = true;
  } else {
    deleteProjectile = false;
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#control {
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: 0%;
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
#showData {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: 0%;
}
p#data1 {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: 0%;
  left: auto;
}
p#data2{
  top: 90px;
  bottom: auto;
  right: 0%;
  left: auto;
}
p#data3{
  top: 140px;
  bottom: auto;
  right: 0%;
  left: auto;
}
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
/*https://github.com/Trung0246/Shmup/tree/development-1.2%2B*/
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Trung0246/Shmup/7e079cec9a7d478ad5add01a6c97e3717ae1a600/build/Shmup.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Trung0246/Shmup/d0e087c7ca5f6014e42a3fdcb6fee1a2f0e800af/plugins/basicProjectile.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="control">
    <button id="evalScript">Run script</button>
    <button id="clearTask">Clear task</button>
    <button id="clearProjectile">Clear projectile</button>
    <div id="showData">
      <p id="data1"></p>
      <p id="data2"></p>
      <p id="data3"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

PS: Really sorry for long snippet :(, anyone can edit to hide html and css part?

P.S.S: Click both "Clear task" and "Clear projectile" for delete all bullet

When you click "Run script", you will see the problem that bullet when touching border will bounce back not smoothly, and I want it to be smooth curve...

How to do it? And explaination behind it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "smooth curve". Do you want to avoid the "dent" where projectiles meet the wall and bounce? If so, you need to repel them progressively (with a force) instead of bouncing them right back (with an impulse).

Comment: Yeah, it's quite unclear what the issue is...

Comment: @Quentin yep, still cant figure it out

Comment: Maybe it's because you have a square border?

Comment: @GMR516 maybe... but I don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite make head or tail of your code, and not knowing Javascript doesn't help (that's Javascript, right?)

However the solution to your problem is more of a physics one: when you detect that a projectile should bounce, you directly change its direction. This leads to the abrupt dent in the trajectories.

If you want more of a "smooth" bounce, you need to allow your bullets to decelerate, then accelerate towards the opposite direction. In other words, replace your walls with force fields.

Adding forces is much, much easier to do with cartesian vectors (i.e. `(x, y)` pairs) than with polar vectors (the `(direction, magnitude)` pairs you have). I suggest you switch to cartesian.

When it's done, you can use an approximation of Newton's physics to apply your forces directly on the projectile's speed:

```
// Returns the sum of the forces from all walls
vec2 getWallForce(vec2 pos) {

    float margin = /* AoE of the forcefield around the walls */;
    float strength = /* Strength of repulsion */;

    // Assumes boolean-to-int conversion
    return strength * vec2{
        (pos.x < margin) - (pos.x > data.scene.size.x - margin),
        (pos.y < margin) - (pos.y > data.scene.size.y - margin)
    };
}

// ...

foreach bullet {
    vec2 wallForce = getWallForce(bullet.pos);

    // Integrate with the elapsed time
    bullet.speed += wallForce * deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the part of strength * vec2, syntax is weird... (C++?) and what type of data vec2 class hold, and the data that getWallForce return?

Comment: @Trung0246 `vec2` would be a simple pair of floats to store a cartesian vector. Multiplying it with a float should multiply both coordinates by the float.